# How to import TimeSeriesNet() from nnet-ts in mac ox?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, time-series

I have installed nnet-ts in mac using

```
pip install nnet-ts
```

All the dependency libraries are already installed. But while importing module nnet_ts

```
from nnet_ts import *
```

following error is generated

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-7-ad5e84de7763> in <module>
----> 1 from nnet_ts import *
      2 count=0
      3 ahead=12
      4 pred=[]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nnet_ts/__init__.py in <module>
      5 from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
      6 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
----> 7 from TimeSeriesNnet import TimeSeriesNnet

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TimeSeriesNnet'
```

I try to figure out from this thread [Using the TimeSeriesNnet() method from the nnet_ts module throws NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673380/using-the-timeseriesnnet-method-from-the-nnet-ts-module-throws-nameerror)

but does not work for MAC. How can we solve this problem in MAC OX?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/hawk31/nnet-ts/issues/3) suggestion? I.e. edit the `__init__.py` module: `from .TimeSeriesNnet import TimeSeriesNnet`? Not the most elegant fix but if it works, it works...

Comment: @FlorianBlume, yes it works. Thank you so much. Btw, my jupyter kernel died after running and prompt me to re-start again. Could you suggest some idea?

Comment: Your information is a bit too vague to give some advice on the other issue. Maybe post a new question with more details if this keeps recurring. And don't forget to post an answer to your question!

Comment: Thanks @FlorianBlume for your suggestion. I got the idea and solve from the link:  
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016532/jupyter-notebook-kernel-dies-when-importing-tensorflow-1-5-0

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to post an answer to this question here, so that users who stumble across the same issue and find your question see the answer as well ;)